# add values from struct keys spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col", expr("transform(col, x -> struct(x.amt as amt))"))
Output: [{"amt": 10000}, {"amt": 20000}]
```

I want to add all the values for amt key. So I am getting all the values into a list as below:

```
df.withColumn("list_val", expr("transform(col, x -> x.amt)"))
Output: [10000,20000]
```

To sum the values, I have the following code, but getting error **cannot resolve aggregate**

```
.withColumn("amount", aggregate($"list_val", lit(0), (x, y) => (x + y)))
```

How do I fix this code or is there any better way to add the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggregate` should be used inside a Spark SQL `expr` for Spark 2.4. Also it should be better to add a type cast to ensure there is no type mismatch:

```
df.withColumn("amount", expr("aggregate(list_val, 0, (x, y) -> (x + int(y)))")

// for float type; for double type, replace "float" with "double"
df.withColumn("amount", expr("aggregate(list_val, float(0), (x, y) -> (x + float(y)))")
```

In Scala API that would be

```
df.withColumn("amount", aggregate($"list_val", lit(0), (x, y) => (x + int(y))))

df.withColumn("amount", aggregate($"list_val", lit(0f), (x, y) => (x + float(y))))

df.withColumn("amount", aggregate($"list_val", lit(0.0), (x, y) => (x + double(y))))
```

Comment: I am using Spark 3.0. While I am running the below 
```
df.withColumn("premium", expr("aggregate(list_val, 0, (x, y) => (x + y))"))
```
I am getting below error:
```
extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'CLONE',

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. Should be `->`, not `=>`.

Comment: i had tried that earlier but then i got 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aggregate
is there any other way I can do the sum?

Comment: You might need a type cast to make sure the types are correct. See edited answer

Comment: thanks the below worked:
.withColumn("amount", expr("aggregate(list_val, double(0), (x, y) -> (double(x) + double(y)))"))